# Python 2.7.6 on Ubuntu 12.04 How to?

Tags: 12.04, python, python-2.7

I'm developer and I need to make my enviroment work with Python 2.7.6 (not 2.7.3) on the Ubuntu 12.04. Please, provide me some notes how to do that?

Comment: Thanx, ! I upgraded form python 2.7.5+ to 2.7.6 on Ubuntu 13.10.I didn't have the need to use the command "sudo update-alternatives --config python", but I had to use "sudo make install" in order to get the permissions to install the update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ubuntu 12.04 ships with python 2.7.3. You should be able to download https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.6/Python-2.7.6.tgz and follow the README file. The steps should be simple enough.

```
./configure
make
make install
```

Note that you don't have to remove python-2.7.3 from your system to install an other version. You can switch between different versions using

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

Also, did you check this out?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20445565/ubuntu-12-04-lts-update-python-2-7-3-to-2-7-6-without-breaking-dependencies

Comment: Switching between 2.73 and 2.7.6 does not work for me ("error: no alternatives for python."). The new version seems to have overwritten the old one.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 12.04 or >12.04 this will work perfectly.
Run these simple commands in your terminal:

```
wget  https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.6/Python-2.7.6.tgz  
./configure
make
make install
```

Comment: This answer only shows (in addition to the accepted answer) how to download the file via `wget` from command line. It also misses `tar xf(v)z` command to unpack archive and a `cd` into the folder before doing `./configure` and so on.

Comment: yes that is what only missing in the new_sys_admin answer. This is a complete answer for everyone.